# smarty php : how to pass variable in registerPlugin function

Tags: php, smarty3

i want to know how can i pass variable to function which am registering as plugin with registerPlugin() function of smarty php

how am doing.

i have smarty_get_data function

```
function smarty_get_data($params, Smarty_Internal_Template $template)
{
     // trying to use passed variable 
   echo 'passed var :: '.$params['doma']; 
}
```

variable which i want to pass

```
$doma = 'test var';
```

register as plug-in

```
$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'get_data', 'smarty_get_data', false, array('doma' => $doma));
```

output is blank

> passed var ::

so need help what am doing wrong !

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass the `$doma` into the `registerPlugin` function. You need to pass it when function `get_data` is called (in the template).

First register the plugin:

```
$smarty->registerPlugin('function', 'get_data', 'smarty_get_data', false);
```

Then in the template call the registered function with data :

```
{get_data doma="some text"}
```

Also, please check the documentation of the function here : http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/api.register.plugin.tpl